# Jquery plugin to rotate DIV in 3D

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, 3d, rotation, z-axis

Do you know any jquery plugin that can rotate a DIV in 3D. I have similar size DIVs one on top of the other. You can see them all because they are one on top of the other. I want to rotate them in the z-axis so people can see all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [jQuery Transit](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit) might be what you're looking for.

It can rotate in 3D, and also by using rototeX, rotateY and perspective, which are pretty awesome. I did not see a rotateZ support, but that's pretty much a normal rotate isn't it?

Anyway, I think it's worth checking it out.